# How to Determine Current Lock Screen Provider

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is it possible to determine if the calling application is the current lock screen provider. What I mean by this is that in my app I would like to be able to query whether my app is the current lock screen provider or not. I have set up navigation to the default lock screen page using the following button click event, but I would like to disable the button if my app is already the current provider.

Edit*

I got this idea from the Twitter application, which allows you to make it the lock screen provider, and while it is the current lock screen provider, the button for this is disabled.

```
private async void LockScreenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Launch URI for the lock screen settings screen.
    var op = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-lock:"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [LockScreenManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.system.userprofile.lockscreenmanager%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to find out and prompt with the follow code:

```
if (LockScreenManager.IsProvidedByCurrentApplication == false)
{
    LockScreenRequestResult request = await LockScreenManager.RequestAccessAsync();
    // do something with result!
}
else
{
    // we control the lockscreen!
}
```

Comment: Of course, had that from the documentation. I do have one question, however. If I was just performing a quick check like you do above, not actually setting the lock screen, do I need to use a try catch block? I'd assume no, but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: No need for try/catch if just checking IsProvidedByCurrentApplication